# Simplify Boolean Expression $F = A'B + BC'D + BCD' + AB'C

Tags: logic

$$\boldsymbol{F = A'B + BC'D + BCD' + AB'C}$$

as I have tried I just found one expression can be minimized as like

$$= A'B + B(C'D\; \boldsymbol{\mathrm  {XOR}}\; CD') + AB'C$$

Comment: ifnot A then B else (C xor BD)

Comment: what will it's boolean expression ? #DanielV

Answer (score 0):

If you have to stick to the 'normal' Boolean connectives ''and'', ''or'', and ''not'', then you can't really simplify it, but if you can use the $\oplus$ (XOR), then the following works nicely:

$A'B + C(A \oplus B) + B(C \oplus D)$